# Android Room IN condition with list of Entities

Tags: java, android, android-room

Imagine that we have a simple `User` entity:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @PrimaryKey
    public final String id;

    public final String name;
}
```

What I want to do is to find the [intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)) of

1. Sets of `Users` locally stored in Android Room
2. Sets of `Users` just fetched from the remote source

And Here's what I can do:

```
//DAO
@Query("SELECT * FROM User WHERE id IN (:ids)"
List<User> getIntersection(List<String> ids)
```

and use Dao like this:

```
List<User> remoteUsers = getRemoteUsers();
List<String> ids = remoteUsers.stream().map(i -> i.id).collect(Collectors.toList())
List<User> intersaction = dao.getIntersection(ids);
```

What I am wondering is if there is a way that I can pass the List directly as the parameter, something like this:

```
//DAO
@Query("SELECT * FROM User WHERE ???"
List<User> getIntersection(List<User> users)
```

```
List<User> intersaction = dao.getIntersection(getRemoteUsers());
```

Any other simplification suggestion would also be appreciated.

Comment: i doubt this is possible, but it's worth asking

Comment: @a_local_nobody, I agree. I was thinking there might be something like `INNER JOIN` except taking list of entities instead of tables

Comment: i upvoted because i don't know the answer to this and i think it's a valid question, but i've never seen it done, do not think it's possible either but hopefully we both learn something

Comment: I created an issue, feel free to star https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/318054179